# Twilio Voice Meteor App stuck on registering state

Tags: meteor, twilio

Tried to initialize the new twililo voice sdk and stuck on registering. Here is the debug image.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you're using to set up the `Device` in the context of the Meteor app? How are you requesting and creating the access token? Are those `ws` errors anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, this looks like you are trying to use the SDK client-side. You want to use the sdk server-side. Here is how I import mine server-side.

```
const accountSid = Meteor.settings.private.twilioSid;
const authToken = Meteor.settings.private.twilioToken;
const smsClient = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);
```

You could then call a method from the client-side to interact with the Twilio API.